# How to clear a previous interval with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a simple game using React and came across a problem. So whenever you press W A S or D, an interval starts. What I want is whenever the user presses a key, the previous interval is cleared before starting the next one so that only one interval is executing at a time.

```
export default function useGame() {
  const [xpos, setXpos] = useState(250)
  const [ypos, setYpos] = useState(250)
  const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = useState(null)

  const handleKeypress = (e) => {
    let id = setInterval(() => {
      if (e.key === "w") {
        setYpos((prev) => {
          return (prev -= 5)
        })
      }
      if (e.key === "s") {
        setYpos((prev) => {
          return (prev += 5)
        })
      }
      if (e.key === "a") {
        setXpos((prev) => {
          return (prev -= 5)
        })
      }
      if (e.key === "d") {
        setXpos((prev) => {
          return (prev += 5)
        })
      }
    }, 100)
    setIntervalID(id)
  }

  return { handleKeypress, xpos, ypos, intervalID }


//Component file
export default function Game() {
  const { handleKeypress, xpos, ypos, intervalID } = useGame()

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
    console.log(intervalID)
      if (intervalID) {
        clearInterval(intervalID)
      }
      handleKeypress(e)
    })
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keypress", null)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div
      className="character"
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        left: `${xpos}px`,
        top: `${ypos}px`,
      }}
    ></div>
  )
}
```

I've tried storing the interval ID in state but its always undefined in other functions or other parts of the code. How would you guys go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store interval id returned by [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) and pass it to [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) whenever you want to clear that interval.

```
function App() {

        const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
        const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

        const startCounting = () => {
            const id = setInterval(()=>{
                setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
            }, 1000);
            setIntervalId(id);
        }

        return (<div>
            <div>{count}</div>
            <button onClick={startCounting}>Start Interval</button>
            <button onClick={()=>clearInterval(intervalId)}>Stop Interval</button>
        </div>);

}
```

In you question you have created separate interval depending on each condition, and every interval will have different interval id. so better put all condition into single `setInterval` and return its interval id.

```
import { useState } from "react"

export default function useGame() {
    const [xpos, setXpos] = useState(250)
    const [ypos, setYpos] = useState(250)
    const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

    const handleKeypress = (e) => {
        const id = setInterval(() => {
            if (e.key === "w") {
                setYpos((prev) => {
                    return (prev -= 5)
                })
            }
            if (e.key === "s") {
                setYpos((prev) => {
                    return (prev += 5)
                })
            }
            if (e.key === "a") {
                setXpos((prev) => {
                    return (prev -= 5)
                })
            }
            if (e.key === "d") {
                setXpos((prev) => {
                    return (prev += 5)
                })
            }
        }, 100);
        setIntervalId(id);
    }

    return { handleKeypress, xpos, ypos, intervalId }
}
```

Comment: Where would I then use the clearInterval() function?

Comment: In the component I am using the hook in, I logged to the console the "intervalID" value and getting null.

Comment: I've updated the original code in my question, this is how I am trying to log it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from "react"

export default function useGame() {
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(Number(0));
  const [xpos, setXpos] = useState(250)
  const [ypos, setYpos] = useState(250)

  const handleKeypress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "w") {
      if(intervalId > 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
      let id = setInterval(() => {
        setYpos((prev) => {
          return (prev -= 5)
        })
      }, 100)
      setIntervalId(Number(id));
    }
    if (e.key === "s") {
      if(intervalId > 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
      let id = setInterval(() => {
        setYpos((prev) => {
          return (prev += 5)
        })
      }, 100)
      setIntervalId(Number(id))
    }
    if (e.key === "a") {
      if(intervalId > 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
      let id = setInterval(() => {
        setXpos((prev) => {
          return (prev -= 5)
        })
      }, 100)
      setIntervalId(Number(id))
    }
    if (e.key === "d") {
      if(intervalId > 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
      let id =setInterval(() => {
        setXpos((prev) => {
          return (prev += 5)
        })
      }, 100)
      setIntervalId(Number(id))
    }
  }

  return { handleKeypress, xpos, ypos }
}
```

[clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).